# How to match, but not capture, part of a regex?

Tags: regex

I have a list of strings. Some of them are of the form `123-...456`. The variable portion "..." may be:

- the string "apple" followed by a hyphen, e.g. `123-apple-456`
- the string "banana" followed by a hyphen, e.g. `123-banana-456`
- a blank string, e.g. `123-456` (note there's only one hyphen)

Any word other than "apple" or "banana" is invalid.

For these three cases, I would like to match "apple", "banana", and "", respectively. Note that I never want *capture* the hyphen, but I always want to *match* it. If the string is not of the form `123-...456` as described above, then there is no match at all.

How do I write a regular expression to do this? Assume I have a flavor that allows lookahead, lookbehind, lookaround, and non-capturing groups.

---

The key observation here is that when you have either "apple" or "banana", you *must also* have the trailing hyphen, but you don't want to match it. And when you're matching the blank string, you *must not* have the trailing hyphen. A regex that encapsulates this assertion will be the right one, I think.

Comment: You want to match everything except for hyphens?

Comment: I have a much easier example, I have me@company.org and I want to match company in order to hand it over for further processing

Answer (score 485):

The only way not to capture something is using [look-around assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<=123-)((apple|banana)(?=-456)|(?=456))
```

Because even with [non-capturing groups `(?:…)`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) the whole regular expression captures their matched contents. But this regular expression matches only `apple` or `banana` if it’s preceded by `123-` and followed by `-456`, or it matches the empty string if it’s preceded by `123-` and followed by `456`.

| Lookaround | Name | What it Does |
| --- | --- | --- |
| (?=foo) | Lookahead | Asserts that what immediately FOLLOWS the current position in the string is foo |
| (?<=foo) | Lookbehind | Asserts that what immediately PRECEDES the current position in the string is foo |
| (?!foo) | Negative Lookahead | Asserts that what immediately FOLLOWS the current position in the string is NOT foo |
| (?<!foo) | Negative Lookbehind | Asserts that what immediately PRECEDES the current position in the string is NOT foo |

Comment: +1 — In this case, you can work around that by using group 1 rather than group 0, but this is an excellent (and subtle!) distinction.

Comment: @Ben Blank: It definitely depends on how “match” and “capture” are interpreted.

Comment: Not supported in JavaScript, *yay*! would be nice to have a JS friendly method, but not bad at all, +0.5 (rounding up ;D )

Comment: Love look-around assertions! These work great with Ruby as well.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms I checked in JS, and it's working fine, check this [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/55826b09efc9).

Answer (score 17):

In javascript try: `/123-(apple(?=-)|banana(?=-)|(?!-))-?456/`

**Remember that the result is in group 1**

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/bWn12gRMhcHREiKG)

---

Based on the input provided by [Germán Rodríguez Herrera](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41482809/4298200)

Comment: But the OP want to match only "apple", "banana", and "". It's not the case here. See this [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/0571503e7cf1).

Answer (score 10):

Try:

```
123-(?:(apple|banana|)-|)456
```

That will match `apple`, `banana`, or a blank string, and following it there will be a 0 or 1 hyphens.  I was wrong about not having a need for a capturing group.  Silly me.

Comment: This is not correct since it matches, for example, "123-coconut-456".

Comment: Thought you wanted it more general...fixed.

Answer (score 6):

I have modified one of the answers (by @op1ekun):

```
123-(apple(?=-)|banana(?=-)|(?!-))-?456
```

The reason is that the answer from @op1ekun also matches `"123-apple456"`, without the hyphen after apple.

Comment: Comments should be used for improvements and not answers

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
/\d{3}-(?:(apple|banana)-)?\d{3}/
```

Comment: This is not correct since it matches, for example, "123-coconut-456".

Comment: @david: how's that different from your "banana" example?

Comment: @SilentGhost: I *only* want to capture `apple` or `banana` or "". All other values are invalid, as I stated.

Comment: sry, in that case: **/\d{3}-(?:(apple|banana)-)?\d{3}/**

Comment: What this example shows is that it is possible to have a non-capturing group without using lookahead and lookbehind.

Answer (score 0):

A variation of the expression by @Gumbo that makes use of `\K` for resetting match positions to prevent the inclusion of number blocks in the match. Usable in PCRE regex flavours.

```regex
123-\K(?:(?:apple|banana)(?=-456)|456\K)
```

Matches:

```
Match 1  apple
Match 2  banana
Match 3
```

Answer (score 0):

echo '16' | xargs | grep -oP '\d'

Comment: Please add some explanation for your code rather than posting code only. Additional explanation will be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> "123-apple-456, 87568-555"

```
/(\d+-)(?:[a-z]*-?)*(\d+)/
```

> \1\2

```
123-456, 87568-555
```

Comment: This answer needs to be improved with any amount of explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`123-(?:(apple|banana)-)?456`

The word in the middle is in capturing group 1 (`.groups()[0]`). If it doesn't exist, this returns `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression to test:

> \d{3}-(?:(apple|banana)-|)\d{3}

matches strings with three digits, followed by either "apple-", "banana-", or nothing, and ending with three digits. It captures "apple" or "banana" if present. It also captures result as empty when there is no "apple" or "banana"

[Sandbox test link](https://rubular.com/r/6nWzHcZlqP0lMX)

Tested on the following data set:

```yaml
123-apple-456
123-banana-456
123-banana456
123banana-456
123-456
123456
123-coconut-456
123-123-456
123-apple456
```

Found matches:

```json
Match 1
1.  apple
Match 2
1.  banana
Match 3
1.   
Match 4
1.
```

Answer (score -5):

By far the simplest (works for python) is `'123-(apple|banana)-?456'`.

Comment: This would match `123-apple456` so it isn't correct.