# string.IndexOf search for whole word match

Tags: c#, regex, string, substring, indexof

I am seeking a way to search a string for an exact match or whole word match.  `RegEx.Match` and `RegEx.IsMatch` don't seem to get me where I want to be.  
Consider the following scenario:

```
namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = "SUBTOTAL 34.37 TAX TOTAL 37.43";
            int indx = str.IndexOf("TOTAL");
            string amount = str.Substring(indx + "TOTAL".Length, 10);
            string strAmount = Regex.Replace(amount, "[^.0-9]", "");

            Console.WriteLine(strAmount);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

The output of the above code is:

```
// 34.37
// Press any key to continue...
```

The problem is, I don't want **`SUBTOTAL`**, but `IndexOf` finds the first occurrence of the word **`TOTAL`** which is in **`SUBTOTAL`** which then yields the incorrect value of 34.37.

So the question is, is there a way to force `IndexOf` to find only an exact match or is there another way to force that exact whole word match so that I can find the index of that exact match and then perform some useful function with it. `RegEx.IsMatch` and `RegEx.Match` are, as far as I can tell, simply `boolean` searches.  In this case, it isn't enough to just know the exact match exists.  I need to know where it exists in the string.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: `str.IndexOf(" TOTAL ");` But it's ugly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use Regex

```
string str = "SUBTOTAL 34.37 TAX TOTAL 37.43";
var indx = Regex.Match(str, @"\WTOTAL\W").Index; // will be 18
```

Comment: Thanks!  That's much cleaner!  Who knew there was a ".Index" hanging off of RegEx.Match?  :) :) :)

Comment: A bit ago, there was a post on this answer using a RegEx pattern that returned the number following the exact match for "TOTAL".  Did anyone else see it?  Anyone care to weigh in on such a pattern?

Comment: @DJ Are you looking for something like `var val = Regex.Match(str, @"\WTOTAL\W\s*([0-9\.]+)").Groups[1].Value;`

Comment: WOW!  I have got to learn more about RegEx.  It seems very powerful, if not very intuitive.  Thanks LB!

Answer (score 6):

My method is faster than the accepted answer because it does not use Regex.

```
string str = "SUBTOTAL 34.37 TAX TOTAL 37.43";
var indx = str.IndexOfWholeWord("TOTAL");

public static int IndexOfWholeWord(this string str, string word)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < str.Length && 
        (j = str.IndexOf(word, j, StringComparison.Ordinal)) >= 0; j++)
        if ((j == 0 || !char.IsLetterOrDigit(str, j - 1)) && 
            (j + word.Length == str.Length || !char.IsLetterOrDigit(str, j + word.Length)))
            return j;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: This is also more flexible as it returns -1 if TOTAL is NOT in the line.  The Regex above returns 0.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**word boundaries**, `\b`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324676/what-is-a-word-boundary-in-regex-does-b-match-hyphen), and the [`Match.Index` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.index?view=net-5.0):

```cs
var text = "SUBTOTAL 34.37 TAX TOTAL 37.43";
var idx = Regex.Match(text, @"\bTOTAL\b").Index;
// => 19
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/a0IpwN).

The `\bTOTAL\b` matches `TOTAL` when it is not enclosed with any other letters, digits *or underscores*.

If you need to count a word as a whole word if it is enclosed with underscores, use

```cs
var idx = Regex.Match(text, @"(?<![^\W_])TOTAL(?![^\W_])").Index;
```

where `(?<![^\W_])` is a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a character other than a non-word and underscore immediately to the left of the current location (so, there can be a start of string position, or a char that is a not a digit nor letter), and `(?![^\W_])` is a similar negative lookahead that only matches if there is an end of string position or a char other than a letter or digit immediately to the right of the current location.

If the boundaries are whitespaces or start/end of string use

```cs
var idx = Regex.Match(text, @"(?<!\S)TOTAL(?!\S)").Index;
```

where `(?<!\S)` requires start of string or a whitespace immediately on the left, and `(?!\S)` requires the end of string or a whitespace on the right.

**NOTE**: `\b`, `(?<!...)` and `(?!...)` are [*non-consuming* patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926451/how-to-match-but-not-capture-part-of-a-regex), that is the regex index does not advance when matching these patterns, thus, you get the exact positions of the word you search for.

Answer (score 2):

To make the accepted answer a little bit safer (since `IndexOf` returns -1 for unmatched):

```
string pattern = String.Format(@"\b{0}\b", findTxt);
Match mtc = Regex.Match(queryTxt, pattern);
if (mtc.Success)
{
    return mtc.Index;
}
else
    return -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

While this may be a hack that just works for only your example, try

```
string amount = str.Substring(indx + " TOTAL".Length, 10);
```

giving an extra space before total. As this will not occur with `SUBTOTAL`, it should skip over the word you don't want and just look for an isolated `TOTAL`.

Comment: LOL!!!  Why didn't I see that!  It is a bit "hacky" but for my example only, it should work.  I would really like to see if there is a way to force the whole word match in a more clean approach, but will mark this as the answer if I don't see a more refined answer in a day or so.  THANKS MUCH!!!  :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the Regex solution from L.B. too, but if you can't use Regex, then you could use String.LastIndexOf("TOTAL"). Assuming the TOTAL always comes after SUBTOTAL?

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)