# Test but not select with regex

Tags: regex, pycharm

I am trying to test for an expression but not to select it.
I need that for selecing custom TODOs in the IDE Pycharm.
I want to select comments that have the word `to-cleanup` in them.

When I do the following: `# \b.*to-cleanup\b.*` it also selects the `#`. I'm pretty sure there must be a way to test for the existence of `#` but not to select it.

I just read the documentation for regex that Pycharm Help has, so I don't know how to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926451/how-to-match-but-not-capture-part-of-a-regex), but couldn't understand how to fit it into what I need.

Comment: You can use a positive lookbehind: `(?<=#) \b.*to-cleanup\b.*`

Comment: looks like you want a look behind like `(?<=#)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=#) .*\bto-cleanup\b.*
```

The regex matches (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fJ1qB6/1)):

- `(?<=#)` - a space preceded with a `#` symbol
- `.*` - 0 or more characters other than a newline up to the last
- `\bto-cleanup\b` - whole word `to-cleanup`
- `.*` - 0 or more characters other than a newline (up to the end of the line).

This lookbehind is fixed-width and only checks if the space is preceded with `#` while the `#` itself is not part of the match.

See [**lookarounds** details at regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)