# How to extract value from shell and regex

Tags: regex, shell, unix, grep

I have a string "12G 39G 24% /dev" . I have to extract the value '24'. I have used the below regex

**grep '[0-9][0-9]%' -o**

But I am getting output as 24%. I want only 24 as output and don't want '%' character. How to modify the regex script to extract only 24 as value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to just `grep` again for the digits:

```
grep -o '[0-9][0-9]%' | grep -o '[0-9][0-9]'
```

However, if you want to accomplish this with a single regex, you can use the following:

```
grep -Po '[0-9]{2}(?=%)'
```

Note the `-P` option in this case; vanilla `grep` doesn't seem to support the `(?=%)` "look-around" part.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way not to capture something is using [look-around assertions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):
Use it like this

```
grep -oP '[0-9][0-9](?=%)'
```

---

It's worth noting that [GNU grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/) support the `-P` option to enable Perl compatible regex syntax, however it is not included with OS X. On Linux, it will be available by default. A workaround would be to use `ack` instead.

But I'd still recommend to use GNU grep on OS X by default. It can be installed on OSX using Homebrew with the command `brew grep install`

---

Also, see [How to match, but not capture, part of a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926451/how-to-match-but-not-capture-part-of-a-regex)

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed as an alternative:

```
sed -rn 's/(^.*)([[:digit:]]{2})(%.*$)/\2/p' <<< "12G 39G 24% /dev"
```

Enable regular expressions with -r or -E and then split the line into 3 sections represented through parenthesis. Substitute the line for the second section only and print.

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk`:

```sh
awk '{print $3+0}'
```

The value you seek is in the third field, and adding a zero coerces the string to a number, so `%` is removed.