# Regex match but do not capture with a ".*"

Tags: regex

I have two blocks of code.

```
<TabItem Header="{materialDesign:PackIcon Kind=Bank, Size=24}"
                     Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignNavigationRailTabItem}"
                     ToolTip="Example">
```

and

```
<Button Header="{materialDesign:PackIcon Kind=Bank, Size=24}"
                     Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignNavigationRailTabItem}"
                     ToolTip="Example">
```

I to select the ToolTip="Example" part and replace it. However, I only want to select the ToolTip that is inside the TabItem block. I can select it with:

```
ToolTip\=\"(.*?)\"
```

That selects the one in the Button block as well. I used this [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926451/how-to-match-but-not-capture-part-of-a-regex) to try and solve my issue, but I could not figure out how to make it work with a ".*".

So my criteria is:

1. Must begin with '<TabItem'
2. Must contain 'ToolTip=".*"'
3. Must end with ">"

Is what I am trying to achieve possible? If so, how could I achieve this?

Comment: It would be better to use a DOM parsing library than regular expression to process HTML.

Comment: You can't parse HTML with regular expressions. There's no notion of "inside" or elements in regular expressions. The conditions you described aren't enough to detect an element - what if there are a lot of `TabItem`s? You'd have to match the end tag. But what if `TabItem` is an empty element, ie `<TabItem ....... />` ? What if one of the `TabItem`s hase no tooltip? The regex would keep searching until it found a `Tooltip` no matter where it came from

Comment: Why do you need to not capture part of it? If you're doing a replacement, just copy that part into the replacement.

Comment: @Barmar I want to replace the ToolTip on 100+ instances. But I only want to replace them within the TabItem block. I can do it manually, but I wanted to try and find a regex solution to solve the issue.

Comment: Let's say you tried `<TabItem .*? Tooltip="(?<tip>.*?)"` to capture the first tooltip after `<TabItem`. That would match `<TabItem /><Button Tooltip="blah" />` as well. If you added the end tag, you wouldn't be able to catch empty elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
<TabItem\b[^>]*\bToolTip="([^"]*)"[^>]*>
```

Using `[^>]*` ensures that the regexp won't match across multiple tags, and `[^"]*` won't allow that capture group to go outside the quoted tooltip attribute.

You can't use a lookaround for this, because you'd need a lookbehind to match the part before `ToolTip`, and lookbehinds have to be fixed length in most regexp engines.

If you're using this in a regexp replacement, put the parts that should be kept in the replacement into capture groups, and then use back-references in the replacement string.

Comment: Wouldn't `ToolTip="(.*?)"` be enough?

Comment: It's probably equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TabItem.*?ToolTip="(.*?)">
```

if you use this regex then you will be able to get the value inside the tooltip as a list you can use them in regex with `$1` here $1 will be the value inside the first tooltip and $2 will have the second if there is a second match for this regex