# RegEx find words start Capital letter end colon

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm new to RegEx and JavaScript and I was wondering if anyone knew what the RegEx would be for detecting word start Capital letter end colon:

**Example string:

```
 const myStr=`Title: Consectetur adipiscg elit  Description: Sed sit
 amet eros diam Details: Vestibulum a eros ut massa interdum
 consectetur  Article number: AYHMNR`;
```

Result:

> Title,Description,Details, Article number

I used:

`/[:]/i` and `\b[A-Z(...)].*?\b` [here](https://rubular.com/r/5bvluLp4QjWHot)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use:

```
\b[A-Z]\w*(?:\s+[A-Z]\w*)*(?:\s+[a-z]\w*)*(?=:)
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `[A-Z]\w*` Match an uppercase char A-Z and optional word chars
- `(?:\s+[A-Z]\w*)*` Optionally repeat words that start with an uppercase char
- `(?:\s+[a-z]\w*)*` Optionally repeat matching words that start with a lowercase char a-z
- `(?=:)` Positive lookahead, assert `:` directly to the right of the current position

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/cO0VVm/1).

**Note** that `\s` can also match a newline.

An example matching spaces without newlines using `[^\S\n]*` instead of `\s*`

```js
const regex = /\b[A-Z]\w*(?:[^\S\n]+[A-Z]\w*)*(?:[^\S\n]+[a-z]\w*)*(?=:)/g;
const s = `Title: Consectetur adipiscg elit  Description: Sed sit
> amet eros diam Details: Vestibulum a eros ut massa interdum
> consectetur  Article number: AYHMNR
Title tEST: testing
Big red car:1, Small green ship: 2, Green Forest:3`;
console.log(s.match(regex))
```

Answer (score 1):

You’ll need to at least target the colon to achieve what you’re looking for. How about something like this:

```
(\b[A-Z].*?\b)+\:
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const myStr = 'Title: Consectetur adipiscg elit  Description: Sed sit amet eros diam Details: Vestibulum a eros ut massa interdum consectetur  Article number: AYHMNR';
const regex = /([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+(?:\s[a-z]+)?):/g;
const getFirstGroup = () => {
  return Array.from(myStr.matchAll(regex), m => m[1]);
}

for (const match of getFirstGroup()) {
  console.log(match);
}
```

Output:

```
Title
Description
Details
Article number
```

Comment: how can i find ``` let strA = '10Send Me11Send Me12Send Me13Send Me14Send Me15Only 1 left16Send Me'``` number between  ME and ONLY words

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a simple example with the lookahead assertion so you don’t get the colon in the result.

```
[A-Z][a-z\s]*(?=\:)
```

https://rubular.com/r/3PTi0J3BSapk5F

Starts with a capital letter followed by any number of lowercase letters or space and then followed by a colon with a lookahead assertion. For more information on look ahead see this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3926546