# Regex expression is not correct

Tags: c#

I want to use regex to find a text between two words.
This almost works.
But it also returns parts of the words that are searched for.

Result: sub)a(/sub
But I need: a
Only the letter a.
Possibly (sub) and (/sub) can occur several times in the string.

How do I have to change the regex expression?
Thanks.

```
var start = "(sub)";
var end = "(/sub)";
var text = "Border Low P(sub)a(/sub) 12";
var text2 = "Border Low P(sub)a(/sub) and (sub)b(/sub)";

Regex regex = new Regex($"{start}(.+?){end}");
var v = regex.Match(text);

// result: sub)a(/sub
```

Comment: The `(` and `)` have a special meaning as a regex pattern. If you want to search for the literal characters you need to escape them. E.g. `"\(sub\)"`

Comment: @NotFound - though OP should be aware of that since `(.+?)` is used

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/ev6K0u/1

Comment: `(?<=\(sub\)).*?(?=\(\/sub\))`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest

```
(?<=\(sub\)).*?(?=\(\/sub\))
```

pattern where.

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=\(sub\))  - look behind for "(sub)", note escapement \( and \)
.*?           - arbitrary symbols but as few as possible
(?=\(\/sub\)) - look ahead for "(\sub)", note escapement \(, \/ and \)
```

**Code:**

```
var text = "Border Low P(sub)a(/sub) and (sub)b(/sub)";

Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=\(sub\)).*?(?=\(\/sub\))");

// Let's have an array of matches
var v = regex
  .Matches(text)
  .Cast<Match>()
  .Select(match => match.Value)
  .ToArray();

// Let's have a look
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", v));
```

**Output:**

```
a, b
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oIfPnE)

**Edit:**

If you want to *build* the pattern from given `start` and `end` use `Regex.Escape`, e.g.

```
var start = "(sub)";
var end = "(/sub)";
        
Regex regex = new Regex(@$"(?<={Regex.Escape(start)}).*?(?={Regex.Escape(end)})");
```

Comment: why the look behind/ahead though? seems unncessary.

Comment: I would skip look ahead/behind as there are named groups that could be used with more ease.

Comment: okay, I believe I get it now because of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926451