# Regular expression

Tags: regex, pcre

I would like to have a regular expression to get the number between the '_' and the '/' only and I want to match numbers 1 to 9999 and exclude numbers that are only 0’s

```
catalogue/tipping-the-velvet_999/index.html
catalogue/soumission_998/index.html
catalogue/the-requiem-red_995/index.html
catalogue/the-black-maria-1700-1749_991/index.html
catalogue/olio_984/index.html
catalogue/mesaerion-the-best-science-fiction-stories-1800-1849_983/index.html
```

Thanks

I'd like to get the list of numbers!

Comment: So look for `_`, followed by a number, followed by `/`.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please [edit] your question to add your own attempts.

Comment: yes I got this answer _999 and not 999.

Comment: After a research, I can use this expression using 2 groups. r"(_)(\d{1,})"

Comment: @spyhabs Did you verify that using 2 groups `(_)(\d{1,})` works (that is, _not_ matching) when the number is outside the range 1-9999? I think you'll find that it does not work according to the requirements you gave us.

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake....  {1,4} !

Comment: @spyhabs That would still accept `0` which is outside the range though

Answer (score -1):

To get just the number out of a line, you can use the regex `(?<=_)[1-9]\d{0,3}(?=/)`.

- `(?=_)` uses [look-around assertions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926451/how-to-match-but-not-capture-part-of-a-regex) to require that the match be preceded by `_` but doesn't include it the result.
- `[1-9]` matches a single digit that's not `0`.
- `\d` matches digits 0 through 9.
- `{0,3}` means zero to three characters. So taken together, `\d{0,3}` will match up to three digits together.
- `(?=/)` uses a lookbehind to require that `/` follows the match, but doesn't include it in the result.

Note that this regex will work for a single line of input; you will want to loop over all the lines to get out all applicable numbers.

Comment: Thanks, so I have some process to do.  I cannot get a direct number without no manipulation with the data.

Comment: @spyhabs regex only deals with text - this would give you a string containing only numbers, which can be cast to an int using whichever language you like.

Comment: @MikeSadler True, but it would give OP  `_0/` which requires some minor processing plus that `0` is outside the range instead of `1-9999` as requested.

Comment: @spyhaps, you could probably do something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926451/how-to-match-but-not-capture-part-of-a-regex to just match the numbers. But I don't think you can have a single regex do matches for every line at once (like Mike Sadler pointed out, regex is the wrong tool for things beyond just text-matching), so I expect you’ll have to do outside-of-regex processing regardless.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo – That’s correct, it would match 0, 00, 000, and 0000. My understanding of the question was that it was “the data will have numbers in the range 1 to 9999” rather than “I want to match numbers 1 to 9999 and exclude numbers that are only 0’s.” (@spyhaps, if that’s incorrect, would you edit your question to clarify this?)

Comment: @BlueQuark Then why care about the upper limit? Why not simply `_\d+/` ?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I edited the message to clarify this.

Comment: @spyhabs Ok, that's how I interpreted it all along, but good that you made it even clearer. Did you try the solution I suggested in my answer? It is supposed to do exacly what you asked for.

Answer (score -1):

You can capture the number between `_` and `/`:

```
_([1-9]\d{0,3})\/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8PYjgS/1)

This makes sure that the number starts with `[1-9]` and is followed by 0-3 of any digits. `_0/` will therefore not match.

- `_` - a literal `_`
- `(` - start of capture group

  - `[1-9]` - match on digits 1-9
  - `\d{0,3}` - match on digits 0-9 zero to three times
- `)` - end of capture group
- `\/` - a `/` (depending on the [pcre](/questions/tagged/pcre) interface you use, escaping the `/` with `\`  may not be needed)